# postfix Mail filters not running behind a controlled enviornment

Tags: postfix, spf, sid

I have deployed a postfix(2.6.6) server for email receiving. On this I have configured SenderID + SPF milter, by referring to http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html

The command that I used is as follows:

./sid-filter -u postfix -p inet:10027@localhost -l

Following are my settings in main.cf file:

```
#Milter support for smtpd mail
smtpd_milters =
  inet:localhost:10027,
  inet:localhost:10028

# Milters for non-SMTP mail.
non_smtpd_milters =
  inet:localhost:10027,
  inet:localhost:10028

milter_default_action = reject

# Postfix . 2.6
#milter_protocol = 6
# 2.3 . Postfix . 2.5
milter_protocol = 2
```

Now I have this observation:

1. One of the postfix that is setup on AWS CentOS 5.5 is working fine and is able to receive mails on defined mx record.
2. One of the similar postfix(as in step 1) that is setup behind one of the corporate firewalls is not able to receive any mails and is giving following type of error logs:

> connect from
>   g2txxxxg.austin.hp.com[xx.xxx.96.198]
>
> May 25 13:20:02 g2xxxxxg
>   postfix/smtpd[11733]: C11F9B0194:
>   client=g2txxxxxg.austin.hp.com[xx.xxx.96.198]
>
> May 25 13:20:03 gxxxxxg
>   postfix/cleanup[11814]: C11F9B0194:
>   message-id=AANLkTincPyhJBxcLaF1ReI7rSsZvHWXvh0qaEJuwdm10@mail.gmail.com
>
> May 25 13:20:03 gxxxxxg
>   postfix/cleanup[11814]: C11F9B0194:
>   milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from
>   gxxxxxg.austin.hp.com[xx.xxx.96.198]:
>   5.7.1 Command rejected; from=ashiish.sharma@gmail.com
>   to=9253aphi82iry@xxx.hpxxxx.com
>   proto=ESMTP
>   helo=ey-out-1920.google.com

Here the 'sid-filter' is giving problems.

Any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Ashish Sharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I had to relaunch the sid filter with following command:

./sid-filter -u postfix -p inet:10027@localhost -l -L 8

This resulted in finest log being generated and that convinced me that sid-filter was working correct.

Actually it was the network environment that was not setup properly and resulting in problems.

Thanks to all of those who looked on the problem.

Ashish Sharma